# Parse String to Date with Different Format in Java

Tags: java, string, date

I want to convert `String` to `Date` in different formats.

For example,

I am getting from user,

```
String fromDate = "19/05/2009"; // i.e. (dd/MM/yyyy) format
```

I want to convert this `fromDate` as a Date object of `"yyyy-MM-dd"` format

How can I do this?

Comment: A Date object has no format, it is just a number representing the date. The date can be represented by a String with the format of "yyyy-MM-dd".

Comment: [You can NOT create a formatted Date object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66664791/10819573)

Answer (score 195, accepted):

Take a look at [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). The code goes something like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat fromUser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

try {

    String reformattedStr = myFormat.format(fromUser.parse(inputString));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: instead of getting string format, can i get output in `Date` format?

Comment: @Rachel: Sure, just use `parse` and don't go on to `format`. `parse` parses a String to a Date.

Comment: But `parse` gives me in `date format` as `Fri Jan 06 00:01:00 EST 2012` but it need in `2012-01-06` date format

Comment: @Rachel it is because when you call `System.out.println(anyDateObject)` the default toString() method is called which has been said to print in that format e.g. `Fri Jan 06 00:01:00 EST 2012`. You need to override it to suit your needs.

Comment: @Rachel you must see [toString() for Date Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29) to understanding why it works that way.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: @Rachel You are asking the impossible. As Carlos Heuberger said in a comment to the question, a `Date` hasn’t got a format. As in cannot have.

Comment: input and output is string here but questions says something different

Answer (score 17):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse( 
    "19/05/2009" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) 
)
```

## Details

The other Answers with `java.util.Date`, `java.sql.Date`, and `SimpleDateFormat` are now outdated.

## `LocalDate`

The modern way to do date-time is work with the java.time classes, specifically `LocalDate`. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

## `DateTimeFormatter`

To parse, or generate, a String representing a date-time value, use the [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" );
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "19/05/2009" , f );
```

Do not conflate a date-time object with a String representing its value. A date-time object **has *no* format**, while a String does. A date-time object, such as `LocalDate`, can *generate* a String to represent its internal value, but the date-time object and the String are separate distinct objects.

You can specify any custom format to generate a String. Or let java.time do the work of automatically localizing.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.FULL )
                     .withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) ;
String output = ld.format( f );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "ld: " + ld + " | output: " + output );
```

> ld: 2009-05-19 | output: mardi 19 mai 2009

[See in action in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/4xOyiS).

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 13):

Use the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class:

```
private Date parseDate(String date, String format) throws ParseException
{
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    return formatter.parse(date);
}
```

Usage:

```
Date date = parseDate("19/05/2009", "dd/MM/yyyy");
```

For efficiency, you would want to store your formatters in a hashmap. The hashmap is a static member of your util class.

```
private static Map<String, SimpleDateFormat> hashFormatters = new HashMap<String, SimpleDateFormat>();

public static Date parseDate(String date, String format) throws ParseException
{
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = hashFormatters.get(format);

    if (formatter == null)
    {
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        hashFormatters.put(format, formatter);
    }

    return formatter.parse(date);
}
```

Comment: CAVEAT!! The idea is good, but the implementation is not. DateFormats must not be stored statically, because they are not thread-safe! If they are used from more than one thread (and this is always risky with statics). FindBugs contains a detector for this (which I happened to contribute initially, after I got bitten. See http://dschneller.blogspot.com/2007/04/calendar-dateformat-and-multi-threading.html :-))

Comment: Your blog entry is an interesting read :-) What if the parseDate-method itself i synchronized? The problem though is that it would probably slow the code down...

Comment: As long as the parseDate method was the only method accessing the map, synchronizing it would work. However this would - as you say - introduce a bottleneck.

Answer (score 8):

**Convert a string date to java.sql.Date**

```
String fromDate = "19/05/2009";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
java.util.Date dtt = df.parse(fromDate);
java.sql.Date ds = new java.sql.Date(dtt.getTime());
System.out.println(ds);//Mon Jul 05 00:00:00 IST 2010
```

Answer (score 5):

Check the javadocs for [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) It describes everything you need.

Answer (score 3):

While [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) will indeed work for your needs, additionally you might want to check out [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), which is apparently the basis for the redone Date library in Java 7. While I haven't used it a lot, I've heard nothing but good things about it and if your manipulating dates extensively in your projects it would probably be worth looking into.

Answer (score 2):

Simple way to format a date and convert into string

```
    Date date= new Date();

    String dateStr=String.format("%td/%tm/%tY", date,date,date);

    System.out.println("Date with format of dd/mm/dd: "+dateStr);
```

> output:Date with format of dd/mm/dd: 21/10/2015

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that you have a string like this :

```
String mDate="2019-09-17T10:56:07.827088"
```

Now we want to change this `String` format separate date and time in **Java** and **Kotlin**.

**JAVA:**

we have a method for extract **date** :

```
public String getDate() {
    try {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.US);
        Date date = dateFormat.parse(mDate);
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.US);
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

**`Return` is this : 09/17/2019**

And we have method for extract **time** :

```
public String getTime() {

    try {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.US);
        Date date = dateFormat.parse(mCreatedAt);
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a", Locale.US);
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

**`Return` is this :** **10:56 AM**

**KOTLIN:**

we have a function for extract **date** :

```
fun getDate(): String? {

    var dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.US)
    val date = dateFormat.parse(mDate!!)
    dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.US)
    return dateFormat.format(date!!)
}
```

**`Return` is this : 09/17/2019**

And we have method for extract **time** :

```
fun getTime(): String {

    var dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.US)
    val time = dateFormat.parse(mDate!!)
    dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a", Locale.US)
    return dateFormat.format(time!!)
}
```

**`Return` is this :** **10:56 AM**

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Also `SimpleDateFormat` cannot parse 6 decimals on the seconds (microseconds)  correctly.

Comment: When I run your second snippet, I don’t get `10:56 AM` as you say I should, but instead `11:09 AM` (tested on Oracle jdk-11.0.3).

Comment: @OleV.V. , If a method be long outdated , it will be deprecate with a line on it as a sign,if a method or class not deprecated we can use it, i dont say it is best way , maybe we have a better way but this way is simple and understandable,if a method or class was old there is no reason that it is troublesome and for use of `DateTimeFormatter` we need to `minsdk 26` or higher then its not good thing

Comment: @OleV.V. But thanks for your comment and about your second comment i can say that i check it many times in two applicaiton  and it return `10:56 AM`

Comment: You’re assuming Android, which the question didn’t. java.time has been backported and can be used on lower Andoird API levels than 26. See [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: So apparently `SimpleDateFormat` confusingly behaves differently on Android compared to the behaviour on desktop Java.

Comment: @OleV.V. , Ok but i use a library when i have no way or that API(library) be very very better than my code,because when you add a library you add some codes to your project that may not be used and this is overload for your project,this is my approach and your approach is respectable for me.

Answer (score 1):

A `Date` object has **no format**, it is a representation. The date can be presented by a `String` with the **format you like**.

E.g. "`yyyy-MM-dd`", "`yy-MMM-dd`", "`dd-MMM-yy`" and etc.

To acheive this you can get the use of the `SimpleDateFormat`

Try this,

```
        String inputString = "19/05/2009"; // i.e. (dd/MM/yyyy) format

        SimpleDateFormat fromUser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
        SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        try {
            Date dateFromUser = fromUser.parse(inputString); // Parse it to the exisitng date pattern and return Date type
            String dateMyFormat = myFormat.format(dateFromUser); // format it to the date pattern you prefer
            System.out.println(dateMyFormat); // outputs : 2009-05-19

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**This outputs : 2009-05-19**

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it, but a very practical one is the use `String.format` which you can use with `java.util.Date` or `java.util.Calendar` or event `java.time.LocalDate`.

`String.format` is backed by `java.util.Formatter`.

I like the omnivore take on it.

```java
class Playground {
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        String formatString = "Created on %1$td/%1$tm/%1$tY%n";
        System.out.println(String.format(formatString, new java.util.Date()));
        System.out.println(String.format(formatString, java.util.Calendar.getInstance()));
        System.out.println(String.format(formatString, java.time.LocalDate.now()));
    }
}
```

The output will be in all cases:

```
Created on 04/12/2022

Created on 04/12/2022

Created on 04/12/2022
```

Comment: That can be useful sometimes, but aren’t you answering a different question? If I understood the OP correctly, they wanted an old-fashioned `Date` object as result.

Comment: @OleV.V. My answer includes the `java.util.Date` object (see above). It is true that I have included some other date types to underline the usefulness of the method and that might be outside of the scope of the question, but in the bigger picture can be useful to know for developers.

Comment: I certainly agree that today we should prefer using the modern `LocalDate` over the poorly designed `Date` and `Calendar` classes, so thanks for including that one.