# Date Format from Date in String to Date

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [String to Date in Different Format in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882420/string-to-date-in-different-format-in-java)

Hi,

I m receiving date as String data type in MM/dd/yyyy format and need to convert in data Datatype in format yyyy-MM-dd to store in DB.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Is this a co-incidence? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027681/parse-short-us-date-into-yyyy-mm-dd-java 5 mins later. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use SimpleDateFormat:

```
SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat destinationFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

String result = sourceFormat.format(destinationFormat.parse(input));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use formatter for parsing the date to particular type

```
 String date="07/25/2011";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            try {
                Date d=dateFormatter.parse(date);

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Ugh, try-catch. I was a magnificently stupid idea to make ParseException checked. Now we have to live with it :(

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this

```
String DATE_FORMAT_NOW = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss";

//Instance of the calender class in the utill package
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 

//A class that was used to get the date time stamp
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_NOW);
```

To print out the time you say

```
System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()) );
```

Cheers