# Format string date

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String to Date in Different Format in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882420/string-to-date-in-different-format-in-java)

I want to convert String to Date in different Format.

`String d = "07:33:01 PM 26/11/2011";`

How can i covert it to `26/11-19h30`?

Comment: Use `SimpleDateFormat`. Search this forum for this and you'll find many examples, and in fact you can start by looking at the "related" links on the right side, lower half of this very page.

Answer (score 2):

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd-H\hm");
date = (Date)formatter.parse(d);
```

You will need to import java.util.* and import java.text.*

Comment: @Zakaria: I did not steal your answer, you might even notice that I posted mine before yours.

Comment: You edited the yours minutes after some code was posted. Anyway, we are in the a community oriented website : you could edit posts or comment them to improve them. There is no concurential goal.

Comment: But mine was first of all. Seriously, though this sort of question has been asked and answered so many times here, another similar question without the original poster showing his actual problem is really not much more than clutter.

Comment: totally agree lol come on guys, we are not children ... @HovercraftFullOfEels : this why i give it a point ;)

Comment: @dotancohen : I removed it to avoid this discussion. Anyway ... I could not a post where you suggested to import whatever lib : sorry, it's ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

```
String d = "07:33:01 PM 26/11/2011";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("d/MM-HH\hmm", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(d);
```

Comment: I have tried it. But it also can't.<br>
this is the my problem :<br>
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "09:33:01 AM 26/11/2011"
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)

Comment: Could you post the program you are using to print the answer ? What error did you get ?

Comment: Thank you very much Zakaria. I have done.

Good luck!!!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). You can parse to custom date formats using this class.

Answer (score 1):

```
    String d = "07:33:01 PM 26/11/2011";

    SimpleDateFormat formatterIn = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a dd/MM/yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat formatterOut = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM-HH'h'mm");
    Date date = formatterIn.parse(d);  

    System.out.println(formatterOut.format(date));
```

It converts to 26/11-19h33, do you want to round to 26/11-19h30?

Comment: It is ok.
Thank you very much.

Goog luck!