# change date format in java

Tags: java

I have string in `'MM/dd/yyyy'` format and want to convert it into `'dd-MM-yy'`.

e.g. `'04/01/2012'` should be converted into `'01-Apr-12'`

Can anyone please suggest how to get this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [String to Date in Different Format in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882420/string-to-date-in-different-format-in-java)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please use the search before asking new questions. Many have already been asked and answered.

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat currentFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yy");

String dateInOldFormat="04/01/2012";
Date temp = currentFormat.parse(dateInOldFormat);
String dateInNewFormat= newFormat.format(temp);
```

i think things are pretty simple from here on...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) class in Java. Parse a string with your format, and then output using a different format.

Answer (score 0):

Below is example of date conversion... **For your program, do changes accordingly...**

```
    String dateStr = "Thu Jan 19 2012 01:00 PM";
    DateFormat readFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "EEE MMM dd yyyy hh:mm aaa");

    DateFormat writeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = null;
    try {
       date = readFormat.parse( dateStr );
    } catch ( ParseException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String formattedDate = "";
    if( date != null ) {
    formattedDate = writeFormat.format( date );
    }

    System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Output is `2012-01-19 13:00:00`

### Good Luck