# Android Date displaying

Tags: android, date, time

I've a problem when displaying the date. I do everything fine, the date shows...bad it's not correct!

It says 2012/07/30   when it should be  2012/08/30.

I've checked my date in the mobile and it's correct. Do you have any idea?

Thank you!!

Piece of code:

```
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
 String sDate = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "/" +  c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

 view2.setText("" + et.getText()  + sDate );
```

Comment: "I do everything fine" - apparently not, but it's hard to say *what* you're doing wrong when we can't see your code. Please show us everything relevant.

Comment: Your code is 'right' maybe you should look at `Calendar.getInstance();` Quote: "Returns: A Calendar subclass instance set to the current date and time in the default Timezone." Timezone messed up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you use `DateFormat`

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
view2.setText(dateFormat.format(c.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

The Calendar object does not work as you are expecting it. The get(Calendar.MONTH) returns a constant representing the month of the date, not the number of the month. This subtle difference can be seen here:
[java.util.calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH)

As you will see, the constants reflect a zero-based sequence, starting with January, so that you can use the constants as indexers into an array for month-based lookups.

For your purposes, you could get away with adding 1 to the returned int, but you might want to look at [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) in the java.text. [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882420/string-to-date-in-different-format-in-java) provides a brief overview to get you started.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can instead use this,

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date())
```