# convert XMLGregorianCalendar to date i.e "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss AM"

Tags: java, date, oracle11g

I have a date in XMLGregorianCalendar format like "2013-05-16T09:54:13" which i have to convert to timestamp "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss AM" for inserting into oracle database table using java.

how can i do this in Java?

Comment: A duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882420/string-to-date-in-different-format-in-java

Comment: You don't format timestamp before inserting into DB. You use java.util.Date class.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can do this to return a `Date`:

```
calendar.toGregorianCalendar().getTime()
```

I found that code from [this tutorial](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/02/convert-xmlgregoriancalendar-to-date-xmlgregoriancalendar-java-example-tutorial.html).  From there, you can use a [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to turn it into a string in the format you want.

But, if you're using JDBC to save the date in the database, you probably can pass in the `Date` directly with [this method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate%28int,%20java.sql.Date%29):

```
preparedStatement.setDate(colNum, myDate);
```

Comment: I can't see the getTime() method. Are you talking about a different package than http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html ?

Comment: @ilinca the getTime() method belongs to the GregorianCalendar Class. You need to parse XMLGregorianCalendar to GregorianCalendar using the .toGregorianCalendar() method as show above.

Answer (score 10):

Here is more clear answer:

Get instance of Date from XMLGregorianCalendar instance:

```
Date date = xmlCalendar.toGregorianCalendar().getTime();
```

I found that code from [Convert XMLGregorianCalendar to Date in Java](http://javabycode.com/java-core/java-xml/convert-xmlgregoriancalendar-to-date.html)

Format that Date instance with format "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a", you will get MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss AM format

```
DateFormat  formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
String formattedDate  = formatter.format(date)
```

From [Convert Date to String in Java](http://javabycode.com/java-core/java-common/convert-date-to-string-in-java.html)

For inserting database you would do what Daniel suggested

Answer (score 3):

If you want to insert your date on a database I would first do what Daniel suggested:

```
XMLGregorianCalendar xgc=<assume this is initialized>;
Date timestamp=xgc.toGregorianCalendar().getTime();
```

and later insert it through a PreparedStatement as Timestamp in milliseconds (Epoch time). That way you won't loose precision.

```
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(colNum,new Timestamp(timestamp.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 
    … , 
    myXGC.toGregorianCalendar()
         .toZonedDateTime()
) ;
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the java.time classes that supplanted the troublesome old classes `Date`, `Calendar`, and `GregorianCalendar`.

Convert from the legacy classes to java.time.

```
GregorianCalendar gc = myXGC.toGregorianCalendar() ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = gc.toZonedDateTime();
```

Pass date-time values to your database **as date-time objects rather than as strings**.

If your JDBC driver complies with JDBC 4.2 and later, you can deal directly with java.time types.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , zdt ) ;
```

If your driver is not yet compliant, convert briefly to a java.sql type.

```
myPreparedStatement.setTimestamp( … , java.sql.Timestamp.from ( zdt.toInstant() ) ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the DateFormat class in Java. This should be helpful: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

You can convert XMLGregorianCalendar to java.util.Date Object by using these two lines of code :-

```
Date date = xmlDate.toGregorianCalendar().getTime();
System.out.println("java.util.date :- " + date);
```

To convert to java.slq.Date Object use this code :-

```
long time = xmlDate.toGregorianCalendar().getTime().getTime();
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(time);
```

You can see complete example [here](http://codedestine.com/convert-xmlgregoriancalendar-to-date/)

Answer (score 0):

Please use the function below - just pass the XMLGregorianCalendar instance and date format you want (format example: "DD MMMM yyyy" ->  01 January 2017)

```
public String parseDate(String format,XMLGregorianCalendar XMLdate){
    Date date = XMLdate.toGregorianCalendar().getTime();
    DateFormat  formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    String formattedDate  = formatter.format(date);
    return formattedDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This returns java.util.Date:

```
java.util.Date tempDate = issueDate.toGregorianCalendar().getTime();
```