# Gregorian Date to Date

Tags: java, date-conversion, java.util.date, date, java.util.calendar

This should be quite simple

`customerSearch.get("DateOfBirth")` where customerSearch is a `HashMap<String, Object>` and it's a Gregorian Date.

But I need a normal `Date` object.

I tried

```
Date dateOfBirth = new Date(
        ((GregorianCalendar) customerSearch.get("DateOfBirth")).getTimeInMillis());
```

but said Gregorian Date cannot be cast to Date.

Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert XMLGregorianCalendar to date i.e "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss AM"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706431/convert-xmlgregoriancalendar-to-date-i-e-mm-dd-yyyy-hhmmss-am)

Comment: Why are you fighting with `GregorianCalendar` and `Date`? Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. No one should use them in 2019 IMHO. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Your code runs nicely on my Java 8 and in one run produced a `Date` of `Wed Dec 29 00:00:00 UTC 1999`. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please.

Comment: @ErayBalkanli That question is about `XMLGregorianCalendar`, this one seems to be about `GregorianCalendar` (or else I don’t know, but hardly `XMLGregorianCalendar`). So not a duplicate of that one, possibly of other questions.

Comment: Are you getting the error message on compile time or on runtime? Would you care to quote the error message *verbatim* (paste it into the question)? Thx in advance.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
( (GregorianCalendar) customerSearch.get( "DateOfBirth" ) )  // Retrieve and cast object of legacy class `GregorianCalendar`.
.toZonedDateTime()                                           // Convert from terrible legacy class to modern *java.time* class.
.toLocalDate()                                               // Extract the date-only portion, omitting time-of-day and time zone.
```

## java.time

You are using, and possibly abusing, terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes defined by JSR 310.

- `ZonedDateTime` replaces `GregorianCalendar`
- `Instant` replaces `java.util.Date`
- `LocalDate` replaces `java.sql.Date`

If you must interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, you can convert back-and-forth. Call new conversion methods added to the old classes.

```
GregorianCalendar gc = customerSearch… ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = gt.toZonedDateTime() ;
```

If you want just the date without the time-of-day and without the time zone, extract a `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate dateOfBirth = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

If by `Date` you meant, `java.sql.Date` class, the above line should be used instead making use of `LocalDate`.

If by `Date` you meant `java.util.Date`, that would be the wrong class to use there. That class represents a moment in UTC. By adjusting from the zoned moment in `GregorianCalendar`/`ZonedDateTime` to UTC, you could be changing the date.

## Converting

If you need a `java.util.Date` object to interoperate with old code not yet updated for *java.time*, you can convert. A `java.util.Date` represents a moment in UTC, so we need the equivalent in *java.time*, `Instant`, also a moment in UTC but with a finer resolution of nanoseconds rather than milliseconds.

We can extract an `Instant` from our `ZonedDateTime` seen above. Effectively, this is simply adjusting from a zoned value to a UTC value. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;  // Extract a `Instant`, adjusting from zone to UTC.
```

Use new conversion methods on the old class.

```
java.util.Date myJavaUtilDate = java.util.Date.from( instant ) ;  // Beware of possible data-loss in the fractional second, truncating from nanos to millis.
```

If you need go the other direction, from legacy to modern.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

## Use appropriate types

If you are trying to represent a date-of-birth is is commonly done, with just a date without time-of-day and without zone, then use `LocalDate` in your map. The classes `GregorianCalendar`, `java.util.Date`, and `ZonedDateTime` all represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline. They should never be used for a date-only.

The `java.sql.Date` class *pretends* to be a date-only, but through a terrible design decision as a subclass of `java.util.Date` actually does indeed carry a time-of-day and offset/zone. This class, as noted above, has been replaced with `LocalDate`.

> normal Date object

There is nothing more “normal” about either `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date` than any other date-time class.

- `java.util.Date` represents a moment in UTC, always UTC, despite what its terribly designed `toString` method tells you (a lie). Use `java.time.Instant` instead when you need a moment in UTC.
- `java.sql.Date` is meant to represent a date-only, but as discussed, actually carries internally a time and zone/offset. Use `java.time.LocalDate` instead to represent a date rather than a moment.
- `GregorianCalendar` represents a moment as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a specific region (a time zone). Instead use `ZonedDateTime` for this purpose.
- `java.sql.Timestamp` represents a moment in UTC but with a finer resolution of nanoseconds rather than milliseconds. All the moment-related classes in *java.time* use a resolution of nanoseconds. So for a moment in UTC with a resolution of UTC, use `java.time.Instant` instead of `Timestamp`.

As of JDBC 4.2, we can directly exchange *java.time* classes with a database. So no need to ever touch `java.sql.Date` or `java.sql.Timestamp` again for your database work.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is no java class `GregorianDate`. Unless it is your own class which if so you didn't mention. So, just in case is Gregorian Date just a regular `Date` as most of the world today uses Gregorian calendar? So instances of what class does your map holds in your `HashMap<String, Object>`? If it is just a regular `Date` then your code should be just:

```
Date dateOfBirth = (Date)(customerSearch.get("DateOfBirth"));
```