# How to convert "April 30,2013" into date object?

Tags: java, date

```
String str2="April 30, 2013";      
simpleDateFormat s= new simpleDateFormat();      
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");    
SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");   
Date dateObject = null;
```

I have string like "April 30,2013", I am getting this as string from form. I want to convert this into date object as 04/30/2013. Is there any way to do it?

I tried with simpleDateFormat() but I didn't found proper output.

Comment: Why is dateObject = null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse String to Date with Different Format in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882420/parse-string-to-date-with-different-format-in-java) and also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion

Answer (score 3):

Use `MMMMM dd, yyyy` to parse and `MM/dd/yyyy` to format

Comment: see the related section click on any of those they will give you sample

Comment: You need to use `MMMM`, not `MMM`

Comment: after parsing and format it is in string form ,how to convert it into date object

Comment: parsing is converting from `String` to `Date`

Comment: anything more that 3 `M` is all the same.

Comment: It probably should be parsed as `d`, not `dd`. E.g. you're more likely to encounter April 1, 2013 than `April 01, 2013. Should at least mention that the question asker should think about which is needed.

Comment: @JigarJoshi  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#text

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code.

```
String str2="April 30, 2013";      
SimpleDateFormat input = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");    
SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");   
Date date = input.parse(str2);
System.out.println(output.format(date));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can convert it String date to Date object:

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d,yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat yourNewDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"); 
    Date date = dateFormat.parse("April 30,2013");
    System.out.println(yourNewDateFormat.format(date));
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, very broad answer.

Comment: please add comment it you are going to mark it down , so I can better help

Comment: @PradeepPati I have modified it please take a look. I hope my changes/answer is specific now.

Comment: @PradeepPati take a look now ? any better ?

Comment: this will give you again string, i want the final output as Date object in the specified  format

Comment: @user2032464 the "date" is a date object in above code...the yourNewDateFormat  is just using to format to string in a format you asked for. So, you can just use the "date" object if you only need it as a date object some where in your code

Comment: but here the problem is i am getting date object with value Fri Mar 08 00:00:00 EST 2013 .i have to compare this value with other date which is in the following format 2013-03-08 02:58:27.197. how i ll compare these dates..?