# Converting returned java string into sql smalldatetime

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I am pulling a smalldatetime from SQL Server database into a java class (2014-03-11 11:49:00) and would like to do a comparison of this date-1 and today's date in java.  The only problem is when pulling the date from the database it is assigned to a String variable, therefore I need some way of converting the String to a smalldatetime-1day in the java code.  Also, I need a way to find (todays date) in the same format.

I have looked around for the last hour with little success.

`if((today's date) >= (smalldatetime -1day)) {
  //do something
}`

Thanks!

Comment: You need to convert this string to **any** Date type that supports date arithmetic.  If you do not plan to write the value back to the database you shouldn't even care about its SQL data type.

Comment: possible duplicate of [String to Date in Different Format in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882420/string-to-date-in-different-format-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only assume you are using the ResultSet class to obtain the values from the database. If so the ResultSet class has a method called getTimestamp which returns the value as a java.sql.Timestamp object.

Assuming you have a ResultSet you can write you code like this:

```
java.sql.ResultSet rs = // assuming you already have this;
java.sql.Timestamp time = rs.getTimestamp("columnName");
if( System.currentTimeMillis() >= time.getTime() - ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 ) ) {

}
```

Read the ResultSet [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) for more details.

Comment: This worked like a charm.  I would give you a vote but apparently I don't have that status yet.  Thanks!

Comment: @user1337172 You need to click the big tick button below the arrows to accept the answer.