# How to get Year, Month and Date with Java Spring MVC from JQuery?

Tags: java, jquery, spring, spring-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker

My application is writen in Spring MVC with the frontend with JQuery datetimepicker. Then i try to format the Date in java, here is what i do :

My main.html page

```html
<body>

    <script>
    $(function () {
        $("#Tgl_Trans").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'});
        /* $("#tgl_order").datetimepicker(); */
    });
</script>

        <div class="form-group" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('Tgl_Trans')} ? error">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tgl Trans</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{Tgl_Trans}" class="form-control" required="required" />
                    <span class="help-inline" th:errors="*{Tgl_Trans}">[error]</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</body>
```

that's the JQuery datetimepicker should be
and then here is my object model, which is named orders.java

```java
    @Column(name = "Tgl_Trans")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy/MM/dd")
    private Date Tgl_Trans;

//the getter setter

    public Date getTgl_Trans() {
        return Tgl_Trans;
    }

    public void setTgl_Trans(Date tgl_Trans) {
        Tgl_Trans = tgl_Trans;
    }
```

that's where i alreader format the date

and then here is my jdbc class when i trying to insert into my database, which is named JdbcOrdersInsert.java

```java
    Date tgl_trans = returorder.getTgl_Trans();

    String no_retur = kode_Salesman+ tgl_trans.toString();
```

what i got is the tgl_trans.toString() become something like this "Sat Feb 28 00:00:00 ICT 2015" that the output
how can i format it to be like "20150128"?
even can't do tgl_trans.getYear() <-- it give me a strikethrough and warning. what am i missing here?

Comment: you could use something like `SimpleDateFormat `

Comment: @Outlooker can u give me some example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882420/parse-string-to-date-with-different-format-in-java