# Is there any in built function in Java to remove unwanted data from extracted data

Tags: java

I extracted some text from a text file but now I want only some specific words from that text.

What I have tried is read from that text file and I have searched by using keyword:

```
    FileReader fr = new 
    FileReader("D:\\PDFTOEXCEL\\Extractionfrompdf.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String s;

    String keyword = "dba COPIEFacture ";

    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (s.contains(keyword)) {
            System.out.println(s);
```

I got Output like this: dba COPIEFacture du 28/05/2018 n° 10077586115Récapitulatif de vote facture

But I want only 28/05/2018 This so please help me

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use [String manipulation methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/manipstrings.html).

It's difficult to know the best way to do it without seeing other outputs, but you could probably use `split()` and `indexOf()` to retrieve the date.

There are other, probably more complex, methods. For example, here's a [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34830332/9908251) about retrieving dates from strings using a regex pattern.

Comment: @Deo why it won't work? Have you tried? Can you edit your question with what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    FileReader fr;
    String keyword = "dba COPIEFacture du ";
     String textToFind = "28/05/2018"; // The length usually will not 
                                       // change.You can use value 
                                       // 10(length) instead
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        fr = new FileReader("D:\\PDFTOEXCEL\\Extractionfrompdf.txt");

        int i;
        while ((i = fr.read()) != -1) {
            sb.append((char) i);
        }

        int start = sb.indexOf(keyword) + keyword.length();
        int end = start + textToFind.length();

        System.out.print(sb.substring(start, end));   //output: 28/05/2018

        fr.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
 }
```