# Strings Dates in firebase, retrieve as miliseconds

Tags: java, date

I have some `dates` in `firebase` and i need to retrieve as **Miliseconds** and do some operations with it.
the Date are like String in format `"dd/MM/yyyy"`

I tryed with a code like this, :

```
String myDate = "2014/10/29 18:10:45";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = sdf.parse(myDate);
long millis = date.getTime();
```

My code, basically i tryed to get the storeged String from firebase and convert to a Date for compare with the current day and show the diference of days. the error that I have, is only in the word "parse" of my code

```
refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                           String mydate = model.getParto();
                           SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                           Date date = sdf.parse(mydate);

                        }
                    });
```

but **parse** set an error

image of code and the string date in firebase

[image]

[image: String date in firebase]

hope, someone can help

Comment: Please include the error. I would also recommend [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882420/parse-string-to-date-with-different-format-in-java).

Comment: Removing the Firebase tag, as it's not relevant to the code shown here.

Comment: Show code as text, not images.

Comment: `parse` throws a `ParseException`, which you must catch. But as answered, dont use `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

```java
LocalDateTime
.parse( 
    "2014/10/29 18:10:45".replace( " " , "T" ) 
)
.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) 
.toInstant()
.toEpochMilli()
```

## Need epoch reference

Representing a moment as a count of milliseconds requires a point in time as an epoch reference. You need to state the reference needed in your situation. I will assume the commonly used point of first moment of 1970 in UTC. But there are a couple dozen other points used by various systems. So you need to find out the meaning of your own data.

## Need time zone or offset

Determining a moment requires more than a date and a time-of-day. You also need the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. Again, you need to specify this but did not. Is your example of ten minutes past six in the evening in Tokyo Japan, Toulouse France, or Toledo Ohio US? I will assume you mean an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds. But again, you need to find out the meaning of your own data.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Never use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date`, or the other terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## Date versus moment

Your Question in confused, referring to a date-only value as well as a date with time-of-day represented as milliseconds. These are two different kinds of data.

If representing a date-only, use `LocalDate` in Java and a type in your database akin to the SQL-standard `DATE`. I will ignore this date-only, and focus on tracking a moment.

## Example code

Parse your input as `LocalDateTime`, after complying with standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format by replacing SPACE in middle with a `T`.

A `LocalDateTime` does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. You need to discover the zone/offset intended for you input, and apply. Apply the time zone intended for your input, to produce a `ZonedDateTime`. Or, if UTC (an offset of zero) was intended, apply a `ZoneOffset` to get an `OffsetDateTime` object. At this point we have determined a moment.

Extract a [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) object from the `OffsetDateTime`. Interrogate for a count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of `1970-01-01T00:00Z`.

```java
String myDate = "2014/10/29 18:10:45".replace( " " , "T" ) ;  // Comply with ISO 8601 standard formatting.
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;  // Assuming your data was intended to represent a moment as seen in UTC, with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds.
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;  // Basic building-block class in java.time, representing a moment as seen in UTC.
long millisecondsSinceEpoch1970 = instant.toEpochMilli() ;
```

Your title mentions Firebase, but that seems irrelevant to your Question. so I will ignore that topic.

All the content in this Answer has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

---

## About *java.time*

[image: Table of all date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).